# How to update an HTML table based on a property of object in an array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm new on angularjs, particularly on MEANSTACK.
I have 2 HTML tables, one we name table_1 containing one column with more than one rows, each row contains some value, let's name it "prop". The second table named table_2 contains some information related to table_1.
I also have an input tag for searching/filtering one row in the table base on my research.
input tag:

```
 <div class="input-group search-bar" style="margin-left:5px;">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="searchbar" placeholder="Enter to Search" autofocus>
 </div>
```

Table_1:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="obj in objecList | filter:search" ng-click= updateTable_2($index)"> 
    <td>{{obj.prop}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Table_2:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="data in datas" >
    <td class="col-xs-4">{{data.data1}}</td>
    <td class="col-xs-4">{{data.data2}}</td>
    <td class="col-xs-4">{{data.data3}}</td>  
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
(function(){   
  angular.module('myapp')
   .controller('MyController', MyController)

     function MyController($state,$http,$scope){
       $http.get('api/displayDatas/'+$scope.myList[0].prop)
        .success(function(response){
          $scope.datas = response;
        });

    $scope.updateTable_2 = function(index){
      $scope.myList[0] = list[index];

      $http.get('api/displayDatas/'+$scope.myList[0].prop)
        .success(function(response){
          $scope.datas = response;
        });
    } 
 }
```

My datamodel looks like this:

```
[
  {"data1":"value1","data2":"value2","prop":"value3"},
  {"data1":"value12","data2":"value22","prop":"value32"},
  {"data1":"value13","data2":"value23","prop":"value33"}
]
```

What I want to do is when am searching for a specific row in table_1, I would like the table_2 be updated regarding the value of the row i selected in table_1.
But now, if i filter one row of table_1, the update of table_2 is done by the index I sent to my function updateTable_2 so that it displays the same data than the one a the same position before.
I don't know how to update table_2 in the fine way.
Hope you will understand what I mean.

Comment: What's `$scope.myList` and `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear and the controller logic to fetch data for *table 2* is duplicated.

If you are struggling with passing parameter to your function in cleaner way, here is a way to go.

> Pass the `object` instead of `$index` to the function from mark-up.

It will have below advantages

- Independent of any `ng-repeat` caveat with $index
- Loosely coupled function, less dependent on global(like `objectList`)
- Increase the readability of your code

**Note:** passing entire object instead of $index is not going to hurt the performance as it is just a reference to the existing object. Rather if you pass $index, it is passed as value and hence new memory is assigned local to the function(though irrelevant performance concern).

Here is the modified logic. Check this out on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iUEpoLPrg9i6MZETVMDr?p=preview)

```js
  function MyController($http, $scope) {
    $scope.objectList = [{
      "prop": "value3"
    }, {
      "prop": "value32"
    }, {
      "prop": "value33"
    }];

    $scope.updateTable_2 = function(obj) {
      $scope.activeObj = obj;
      $http.get('data.json') //use obj to pass additional param
        .success(function(response) {
          $scope.datas = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.activeObj = $scope.objectList[0];
    $scope.updateTable_2($scope.activeObj); //initialize the data for table 2
  }
```

```html
<tr ng-class="{selected: activeObj === obj }" ng-repeat="obj in objectList | filter:search" ng-click="updateTable_2(obj) ">
  <td>{{obj.prop}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope It will help you.